# python how to catch suds web service soap errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, soap, suds

I am trying to use `suds` (version 0.6) to connect to a web service,

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client(SOAP_URL, timeout=10)
```

now I sometimes get `timeout` error, so I am wondering how to catch all errors using `suds` when connecting to a web service, and so then in the catch block I can reconnect the web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though all of their errors inherit from `Exception` so to catch all of the errors, you will need to catch this type of error

Otherwise you can look through their [documentation](https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds-pysrc.html) and choose which exceptions you want to handle seperately.

```
try:
    client = Client(SOAP_URL, timeout=10)
except Exception:
    #enter code to reconnect here
    print("Catch block for creating a client connection")
```

Comment: I mean suds specific errors not general ones

Comment: I ended up using `suds.WebFault`